# How to access web page control from web services in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want's to access web page control(show/hide ModalPopup) from web services.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more of what you are trying to accomplish? It may help provider better answers.

Comment: I have one web page named test.aspx page. in this web page i puts ModalPopup.and i have also one web services test.asmx. in this web services i have make one web methode test. Now, i wants show/hide web page's ModalPopup  from this web services Methode Test. How can i access this ModalPopup from my web services.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically web services are meant to be called into, and a result returned.  Calls do not originate in an outbound manner from a webservice by design.  I think you may wish to alter your design.

Alternatively, if you wish to, based on a result from your webservice, you can show or hide the modal by calling the service from Javascript in your test.aspx page and then showing/hiding your modal.

ex:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/WebMethodName",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function() { console.log("show or hide modal"); }
});
```

There are many tutorials on how to do this, [such as this one](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) .

Comment: Thanks for reply me. But i wants to access web page control from web services not calling web services from web page. My code is as under

Comment: ## test.aspx ##
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~Test.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" ValidateRequest="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

    <div>
            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlpopupEntry" runat="server" BehaviorID="ModalPopupEntryBehavior"
            />
            
           <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupEntry" runat="server" Width="300px" Style="display: none; min-height: 160px;">
               
            </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

Comment: ## test.asmx.cs ##

namespace test
{
    public class test : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod()]
        public Test()
        {
            /* From this method i want to show/hide modal pop up on the web page, without page refresh. */
        }
       
    }
}

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do this backwards. As Kyle mentioned, the page calls the service. I've never seen a service make a call to a page. I think you've got to rethink your approach.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a possibility Sanju.  Webservices by definition can not be executed directly, they have to be called from an outside source such as a windows form, console application, or webpage.  You may wish to rethink your approach.  You can hide/show the modal without a page refresh using Ajax/jQuery.  This will let you perform any server side processing you need and also hide/show your modal without a reload.